# How to detach formula.tools in R without restarting the session

Tags: r, detach, unload

I've loaded formula.tools in R. I now want to unload it, but when I run `detach('package:formula.tools', unload = T)` this package still affects the `as.character` function. See below for example.

Can anyone advise how to unload formula.tools such that it doesnt affect `as.character`?

```
# Behaviour of applying as.character to a formula before loading formula tools
as.character(formula(y ~ x)) #"~" "y" "x"

# Behaviour after loading formula tools
library(formula.tools)
as.character(formula(y ~ x)) #"y ~ x"

# Detaching formula tools doesnt change the behaviour
detach('package:formula.tools', unload = T)
as.character(formula(y ~ x)) #still "y ~ x"
```